# Make appended children to also trigger parent element

Tags: javascript

I have appended 2 buttons for each `li` element in my app:

```
  todoLi.appendChild(this.createToggleButton());
  todoLi.appendChild(this.createDeleteButton());
```

Later, I added event listeners to trigger when `li` is moused over and out

```
todosUl.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  let elementMousedOver = event.target;
  if(elementMousedOver.className == 'todoLi') {
    elementMousedOver.lastElementChild.style.display = 'inline';
  }
});
todosUl.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
  let elementMousedOver = event.target;
  if(elementMousedOver.className == 'todoLi') {
    elementMousedOver.lastElementChild.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

Everything works fine for `li` element, but when I mouse over the buttons, that are children of the li element, event listeners stop working for some reason if the bottons were not children of li element after all.

How can I make appended children to also trigger its parent's event listener?

Here is my app on github:  https://mikestepanov.github.io/

repo with files: https://github.com/mikestepanov/mikestepanov.github.io

Comment: can you post the HTML as well

Comment: Not really clear what expectations are. If mouse is over the `<li>` it is over anything that is in the `<li>`

Comment: @JosanIracheta I must say that HTML is implicitly included in the question (`Ul`, `Li`, `Button`s).

Comment: @JosanIracheta here is my HTML : https://github.com/mikestepanov/mikestepanov.github.io/blob/master/index.html

Comment: @Mikhail unless the `button` elements also contain the `className` of "todoLi", they will be disregarded

Comment: @charlietfl if I mouse over li or any child of li, it will trigger li element if I put its children through regular html. However, it does not work for me if I append children in javascript

Comment: @Mikhail if you look at this fiddle, you will notice that the `mouseover` event is being triggered: https://jsfiddle.net/o97jqz50/. I am pretty sure that your `button` elements do not have the same `className` as your `li` elements and therefore your conditional statement is not being executed

Comment: I think this is related to **event bubbling/propagation**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events by default are bubbling up the DOM, therefore the event triggered from the li will trigger the ul as well, the issue is that your if statement will handle only the cases in which the event's target is the ul (className == "todoLi")

```js
var todosUl = document.getElementsByClassName("todo")[0];
todosUl.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  let eOver = event.target;
  if(eOver.className == 'todo') {
  //for the ul
    console.log("I'm handeled from " + eOver.className);
  } else if (eOver.className == 'item') {
  //for the li
    console.log("I'm handeled from " + eOver.className);
  }
});
todosUl.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
  let eOver = event.target;
  if(eOver.className == 'todo') {
  //for the ul
    console.log("I'm handeled from " + eOver.className);
  } else if (eOver.className == 'item') {
  //for the li
   console.log("I'm handeled from " + eOver.className);
  }
});
```

```css
ul{
  padding: 15px;
  background: lightblue;
}
li{ 
  background: grey;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="todo">
  <li class="item">Do it!!</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here lies with the conditional statement. Simply modify your conditional statement to include the `button` element and it should work.

```
todosUl.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  let elementMousedOver = event.target;
  if(elementMousedOver.className == 'todoLi' || 
    elementMousedOver.tagName === "BUTTON") {
    elementMousedOver.lastElementChild.style.display = 'inline';
  }
});
```